# Azure Ad authentication by passing username and password to get the jwt token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Currently i am trying to implement the azure active directory authentication by passing user name and password. So for this i have trying to get the access toke but facing issue to get the same. If i use the client id and client secret then i am able to get the token but when i try to by passing username and password then its not giving the result and throwing the exception :
"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'

Below the code which i am using for this:

```
 /// <summary>
    ///     Working with client id and client secret
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<string> GetTokenUsingClientSecret()
    {
        //authentication parameters
        string clientID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        string clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        string directoryName = "xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
        var credential = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);

        var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + directoryName, false);
        var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential: credential);

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
        }
        string token = result.AccessToken;
        return token;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Not Working with username and password.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task<string> GetTokenUsingUserNamePassword()
    {
        try
        {
            string user = "username.onmicrosoft.com";
            string pass = "yourpassword";
            string directoryName = "XXXX.onmicrosoft.com";
            string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com";
            string resource = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
            string clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

            var credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(user, pass);
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext($"{authority}/{directoryName}");
            var result = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: resource, clientId: clientId, userCredential: credentials);

            return result.Result.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your app a Native app?

Comment: This wouldn't throw that exception, but you're missing the await in front of `authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync`. Also user/pass auth is not supported in .net core for ADAL 3. What platform are you on?

Comment: isn't that also obvious from the error itself. The [Resource owner password credentials flow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wushuai/2016/09/25/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant-in-azure-ad-oauth/) also requires client secret if your app is registered as web application. If it is registered as native application, no client secret will be required.

Comment: Hi Josh, I have tried with await and without await both are not working.

Answer (score 0):

> AADSTS70002: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'.

According to your mentioned exception, I assume that you registry an Azure AD **Web app/API application**. Please have a try to use an Azure AD  native appilcation then it should work. More details you could refer to this document -[Constraints & Limitations section](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/08/using-adal-net-to-authenticate-users-via-usernamepassword/).

> No web sites/confidential clients
>
> This is not an ADAL limitation, but an AAD setting. You can only use those flows from a native client. A confidential client, **such as a web site, cannot use direct user credentials**.

**How to reigstry Azure AD native Application.**

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have already done this but i want to use by entering username and password. Since with the client id and client secrets it is working but not with the username and password.

Comment: `but i want to use by entering username and password`. As I menteioned that If you want to use the username and password, please have a try to registry an Azure AD native application.